Summernote filtering out page tags for DOCTYPE head and body
i'm trying to get summernote to display a full webpage in the editor (technically it is an email template), but it keeps clearing out the <!DOCTYPE>  and  tags which is breaking the page.
Scripts/Styles:
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote-bs4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote-bs4.min.js"></script>

HTML:
<textarea name="summerEditor1" rows="2" cols="20" id="summerEditor1" class="textbox-textbox" style="display: none;">
&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;html lang="en" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"&gt;
    &lt;head&gt;
        &lt;title/&gt;
        &lt;meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/&gt;
        &lt;meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/&gt;
        &lt;!--[if mso]&gt;&lt;xml&gt;&lt;o:OfficeDocumentSettings&gt;&lt;o:PixelsPerInch&gt;96&lt;/o:PixelsPerInch&gt;&lt;o:AllowPNG/&gt;&lt;/o:OfficeDocumentSettings&gt;&lt;/xml&gt;&lt;![endif]--&gt;
    &lt;/head&gt;
    &lt;body style="background-color: #ffffff; margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; text-size-adjust: none;"&gt;
        &lt;!-- Start --&gt;
        Content Goes Here
        &lt;!-- End --&gt;
    &lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;
</textarea> 

Initialize:
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#summerEditor1').summernote({
        width: 685,
        height: 600,
        toolbar: [
            ['style', ['style']],
            ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']],
            ['color', ['color']],
            ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
            ['table', ['table']],
            ['insert', ['link', 'picture']],
            ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview', 'help']]
        ]
    });
});
</script>

Result:
Viewing source shows the DOCTYPE head and body tags removed, but title and meta and some hidden outlook tags remain just fine.
Source of Summernote WYSIWYG
I can't find anywhere in the docs or even the source code of summernote where it filters out specific elements. I understand perhaps for security or XSS it may do this, but for my purposes I don't have this editor available to public anyways, so if I could override it somehow, I would.
